# xamarin pagertabstrip customizations

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Two questions here. First is I want the tabs in the pager tab strip to just fill the bar instead of starting off to the side like so

[image]

Hard to show in this picture but the details tab is the first tab but it starts in the center, and then when I swipe over I see the next tabs.

My next questions is how to change the indicator color, the underlined color that is shown in the image above under the details text.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#9C27B0"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#00e575"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="#00e575"
        android:alpha=".7"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is my current axml

Comment: You could use `pager_title_strip.TabIndicatorColor = Color.ParseColor("#FF4081")`  method to change the indicator color.

Comment: this will work yes, any way to do in the axml file and reference like @color.Accent?

Comment: In native `PagerTabStrip`, I didn't find the solution, maybe you have to  use custom `PagerTabStrip`.

Answer (score 0):

programmatically you can use this :

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = view.FindViewById<PagerTabStrip>(Resource.Id. pager_title_strip);
pagerTabStrip.TabIndicatorColor = Color.ParseColor("#ffffff");
pagerTabStrip.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
```